# How to check if a list have any different value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, operators, logic

I have a table like the following:

```
(date1, date2, date3, date4, date5)
```

and I want to check if ANY of these dates is different than any other.
The trivial solution is:

```
WHERE date1 <> date2
   OR date1 <> date3
   OR date1 <> date4
   OR date1 <> date5
   OR date2 <> date3
   OR date2 <> date4
   OR date2 <> date5
   OR date3 <> date4
   OR date3 <> date5
   OR date4 <> date5
```

Any nontrivial solutions?

Comment: So each row hold 5 dates? and you only care that each date is unique in the row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the table has a primary key, I guess this is not trivial.

```
select key, "There are duplicates"
from
(
    select key,date1 from table
    union all
    select key,date2 from table
    union all
    select key,date3 from table
    union all
    select key,date4 from table
    union all
    select key,date5 from table
) as aa
group by
  key, date1
having 
  count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 5):

Just as an aside, your trivial case can really be simplified to just

```
WHERE date1 <> date2
   OR date1 <> date3
   OR date1 <> date4
   OR date1 <> date5
```

Using [DeMorgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws), this is the same as

```
WHERE NOT(date1 = date2
      AND date1 = date3
      AND date1 = date4
      AND date1 = date5)
```

and then by the [transitive property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation) of the [equality relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equality_(mathematics)), we'd know that if date1 is equal to the other 4 values, then all 5 are equal to each other.

Comment: I had just put in same answer but you beat me...  :)  I agree that this is the simplest solution to the problem.

Comment: +1 Nice to see some logic applied rather then a contrived aggregate

Comment: transitive property of equality just escaped me yesterday... but still, this solution is O(n). I have a system with over 39 columns that may or may not be equal. This is just a simplified example.

Comment: Does this protect us from date2 being equal to date3?

Comment: @automatic: Yes, once we know that date1 is equal to all of the other 4 dates we know (via the transitive property) that date2=date3, date4=date5, etc.

Comment: @lynx: As I originally said, I posted this answer more as an aside rather than as a proposed alternative. I just wanted to point out that your original solution could be somewhat simplified.

Answer (score 0):

group by each value, compare the grouped by count to the original count

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2005+, you could do something like:

```
With Dates As
    (
    Select PK, 'Date1' As DateType, Date1 As [Date] From Table
    Union All Select PK, 'Date2', Date2 From Table
    Union All Select PK, 'Date3', Date3 From Table
    Union All Select PK, 'Date4', Date4 From Table
    Union All Select PK, 'Date5', Date5 From Table
    )
Select D.PK, D.DateType, D.[Date]
From Dates As D
Where Exists    (
                Select 1
                From Dates As D1
                Where D1.PK = D.PK
                    And D1.[Date] <> D.[Date]
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

This was easier for me to picture with an example.  This works, but I am not sure if I have overcomplicated it.

```
CREATE TABLE #Dates( ID int, date1 datetime, date2 datetime, date3 datetime, date4 datetime )
INSERT INTO #Dates VALUES( 1, '1 Jan 2008', '2 Feb 2979', '8 Nov 1967', '31 Dec 2001' ) 
INSERT INTO #Dates VALUES( 2, '1 Jan 2008', '1 Jan 2008', '1 Jan 2008', '1 Jan 2008' ) 
INSERT INTO #Dates VALUES( 3, '1 Jan 2008', '1 Jan 2008', '1 Jan 2008', '31 Jan 2008' ) 
INSERT INTO #Dates VALUES( 4, '1 Jan 2008', '1 Jan 2008', '31 Jan 2008', '1 Jan 2008' ) 

-- look at example data - note only row 2 has all 4 dates the same
SELECT * FROM #Dates

-- return rows where the dates are not all the same 
SELECT ID as RowsWithDatesNotAllTheSame
FROM 
    (
    SELECT ID, Date
    FROM 
        (
        SELECT ID, DateCol, Date
        FROM 
            (SELECT ID, date1, date2, date3, date4 
            FROM #Dates) p 

        UNPIVOT
            ( Date FOR DateCol IN
                (date1, date2, date3, date4)
        ) AS unpvt
        ) x
    GROUP BY ID, Date
    ) y 
GROUP BY ID
HAVING count(*) > 1
```